# How javascript to replace all occurence of slahes forward and backward with ascii character

Tags: javascript

How can we use javascript to replace all occurence of slahes forward and backward in a string with ascii character

Comment: Replace ALL occurrences where? In a string? In the html? On the whole internet?

Comment: `string.replace(/\\|\//g, character )`

Comment: string.replace(/\\|\//g, character ) wont work for back slashes as you want.. eg: "\\\a"

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes are escape characters in Javascript so you need to escape them - which makes for some confusing regex patterns:

```js
var str = "replace / slashes and \\ backslashes with their ascii equivalent";
str = str.replace(/\//g, '&#047;').replace(/\\/g, '&#092;');
alert(str);
```

FYI [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/wP0hH5/1) is a good place to learn about and experiment with regular expressions.